# Vuetify 3 and vue-i18n for tag attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vuetifyjs3

When I need localized text in tag content I do something like this

```
<span>{{ $t('myText') }}</span>
```

But I can't find a way to add localized text for tag attribute. I tried

```
 <v-text-field
    label="{{ $t('myText') }}"
  ></v-text-field>
```

but it didn't work. Could anyone say how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use it directly like any variable :

```
 <v-text-field
    :label="$t('myText')"
  ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But could you explain why ":label=" instead of "label="?

Comment: it's a vue property , so to send a dynamic value(value that is from javascript code) we add the two points, se we let vue know that he will get the value from  a variable and not a static value , please check https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html